# Tricky scope issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pretty straightforward, but it doesn't work the way it should.

```
$(function(){   
  (function(){  
     /**
      * @return boolean Depending on success
      */
     function saveOnServer(data){            
         var result = false;            
         $.ajax({                 
             url : "/post/write.ajax",
             data : data, 
             success : function(response){                      
                  if (response == "1"){                           
                      alert('Response is 1. OK');                          
                      result = true;
                  }
             }
         });             
         return result;
     }                  

     $("#save").click(function(e){              
          e.preventDefault();               
          // This inserts some stuff (on the server), but always returns FALSE
          if ( saveOnServer($("form").serialize())) ){                  
              alert('1'); // This expected to be alerted              
          } else {                 
              alert('0'); // <- But... This will be alerted
          }
     });
  })($);
});
```

The problem is that `response` var always returns `1`, and it alerts `Response is 1. OK` as well. But...

`result` is always `FALSE`. Why?

Comment: I had the same problem sometime back. What fixed it was `promise` and `deferred` object. Its an `async` call so your `if` doesnt wait for the server to give back data. try `async: false` as well

Comment: AJAX, what means the first A?

Comment: He, he @roasted. Exactly. It's like buying a gun but no bullets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return the result of an ansynchronous request before this request has been done.

What you must do is to use the result in the success callback :

```
 function saveOnServer(data, dowith){
     $.ajax({
         url : "/post/write.ajax",
         data : data, 
         success : function(response){
              doWith(response == "1")
         }, error : function() {
              doWith(false)
         }
     });
 }

 $("#save").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); 
      // This inserts some stuff (on the server), but always returns FALSE
      saveOnServer($("form").serialize()), function(result){
         if (result) {
            alert('1'); // This expected to be alerted
         } else {
            alert('0'); // <- But... This will be alerted
         } 
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( saveOnServer($("form").serialize())) ){
```

You are testing the return result from the function saveOnServer(). This returns with the value `false` immediately, it does not wait for the ajax call to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Like most AJAX questions it seems to have something to do with AJAX being async, meaning you want the function to return a value, but the ajax request hasn't returned with it.
Try adding async:false to make sure this is the problem.

```
$.ajax({                 
             url : "/post/write.ajax",
             data : data,
             async:false,
             success : function(response){                      
                  if (response == "1"){                           
                      alert('Response is 1. OK');                          
                      result = true;
                  }
             }
         });
```

if this is it, you should think about redoing your code in a way that functionality is made inside the success function.

Comment: `async:false` is deprecated and should be avoided as it blocks the browser

Comment: @JanDvorak Jquery ver 1.8.1, what should be used then if `async : false` is deprecated?

Comment: @metal_fan callbacks or promises. Don't let your code wait. See the duplicate question.

Comment: What a mess! First time I cant understand the jquery Manuel(about the deprecation). I used -to use async:false as a sanity check if something has gone wrong with ajax calls.

Comment: `async:false` might be useful for debugging, but I try to avoid it nevertheless. Don't ever let it get to the production!